# Android QR Scanner: How to quit ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler to get back to where I came from

Tags: java, android, android-studio, qr-code

In my first steps in exploring Android I now start with QR scanning.

Works all pretty well. But I am not able to come back from the ResultHandler after read the QR successfully to my MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements        
        ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler
{

  private ZXingScannerView mScannerView
  ....

  @Override
  public void handleResult(Result rawResult)
  {
   // my results are ok in rawResult
   // the scanner does not scan anymore but it is still there

   // how to go back to my main activity???
  }

  public void ClickButton (View view)
  {
       mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   

       setContentView(mScannerView);
       mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
       mScannerView.startCamera();         
   }
}
```

}

I tried

```
mScannerview.stopCameraPreview

mScannerView.stopCamera

this.finish

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  // shows my activity_main 
             // but I can not click anything
```

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

I added some code to describe it a bit better. The idea is from

https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-qr-code-scanner-using-zxingscanner-library-tutorial/

Comment: According to your class name you're already in `MainActivity` are you trying to restart the scan process again?

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't clear but I'm assuming you want to restart the scan process. Normally, you'd have to restart the `SurfaceHolder` to be in preview mode. Luckily for you the `ZXingScannerView` already has a method to do that. Call `mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this)` to restart the scan process.

Otherwise can you clarify? You say you want to go back but you're already in `MainActivity`

Comment: I like to have a button that starts the scanning. Maybe other buttons with other functions are there too. If I click the scanning button it should start scanning. If it is finished I like to be back at the view that contains the buttons. As it is with most of the applications that scan codes. It is not only about scanning - it is only a sideshow for something else.

Comment: @chris Using `mScannerView.stopCamera` should work. What does your layout file look like?

Comment: Just the button in a relative layout. Just as in the sample of the link. I see it stops scanning and the handleResult also gives me the result. But it is still in the scan-screen (that stopped recording).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go back into activities/fragments stack you can try `Activity.onBackPressed()`
if you are in a fragment you must call this method against attached Activity

What do you want is not going back to your activity. You want to restore activity's layout.

I think the better choice is to add ScannerView to your activity's layout file with `android:visibility="gone"`. Then in on click you can get this view and change it's visibility to VISIBILE.

Then when you have handled scanning result, you can reset yuoir ScannerView to visibility = GONE

Comment: I can catch it. But how can I set my main activity to active again?

Comment: Explain me: you have Activity A that launch Activity B within is your scanner view. Then you scan and after that you want to go back to activity A?

Comment: let me know if it's solved, otherwise when I go back to home I'll send you a working example

Comment: If I set visibility to false in the ResultHandler it sets it for my main activity. There must be a correct way to close the scanner view.

Comment: yeah, because you are setting your ScannerView as content view of all your Main Activity. But if you set a layout for main activity that contains one single ScannerView and then alter ScannerView's visibility you should solve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132519/discussion-between-firegloves-and-chris).

Comment: I will first have a look at the basics (layouts, activities, ...). Maybe I am doing a little bit to much to fast and I miss something important. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I too was stuck with this problem for an hour, just like you. And later realised..

To solve this problem **DON NOT** implementing the `ZXingScannerView` in the same activity or fragment. Instead start a new activity when you click the button and this activity is just for the `ZXingScannerView`

Once the Scan is done finish and pass the data back to your activity or fragment

Answer (score 1):

Just restart your `MainActivity` before `this.finish()`

the code below will start your main activity through intent...

worked fine for me

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
this.finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

remove from onCreate method this line setContentView(your layout) and when you finish scan write it after you stoped the camera then you can use your layout after scan

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of a look into android concepts and activities.

I put the QR handling in a 2nd activity and it worked well with the finish ().

Thanks for help anyway!!

Comment: I see your issue. Actually everything is occurring in the `MainActivity` according to the link you shared. What's happening is you're replacing your original layout file with the `ScannerView` that's why you can't go back.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too late, but I came with the same problem and I had so find a solution by myself.

You were on the right way, you need two steps more.

I called the methods where I link and set the listener of any buttons
[image: 1]

There are the methods

[image: 2]

Basically you were right where you set the content view, but you need to give the buttons their functionality back.

(I know its late, but better late than never). Good luck!